How to send content into specific boxes in typst?
In typst I can use column to split content/text into columns on the page, is there a way for me to control the spreading/splitting of content into different boxes in a more granular fashion?
For example, say I have a rudimentary dictionary that looks like this

Items:
-
  Section: Foo
  Details:
    ABCD: EFGH
    HIJK: KLMN
-
  Section: Bar
  Details:
    OPQR: STUV
    WXYZ: 1234
- 
  Section: Tres
  Details:
      Random: Thought
      Test: Value



And I am calling it using code that looks like this:-

#let content = yaml("dictionary.yaml") // Get the content file

#let test_item(test_item) = {
  [
    *#underline[#test_item.Section]* \
    #for (hit, details) in test_item.Details [
      *#hit* : #details \
    ] #v(-0.25em) // Add some space for the next section
  ]
}

#box(height: 75pt,
 columns(2, gutter: 11pt)[
    #set par(justify: true)
    #for entry in content.Items {
      test_item(entry)
    }
 ]
)



Is there a way I can direct content to specific boxes in the column.
What function/utility of script should I be reading into?
Right now the compiler decides on its own - but is there a way I can control it so I can tell the compiler to send a item to a very specific column.
This does not have to be done with `columns` if there is some other
way to script what specific section of the page content ends up in.
Updating the question
My goal was to create a dictionary with the following structure:
information.yaml
Items:
-
  Section: Foo
  Details:
    ABCD: EFGH
    HIJK: KLMN
-
  Section: Bar
  Details:
    OPQR: STUV
    WXYZ: 1234
-
  Section: Tres
  Details:
    Random: Thought
    Test: Value


I hoped to generate a document that resembles this:-

(Note: I created this manually, but it's not scalable or easy to automate.)
Following up on the suggestion that grid might be better suited for this than column I tried the following code:
#let content = yaml("information.yaml") // Load the content file

#let test_item(test_item) = {
  [
    *#underline[#test_item.Section]* \\
    #for (hit, details) in test_item.Details [
      *#hit* : #details \\
    ] #v(-0.25em) // Add space before the next section
  ]
}

#grid(
  columns: 2,
  column-gutter: 1em,
  let column_value = 1,
  for entry in content.Items {
    grid.cell(
      x: column_value,
      skills_entry(entry)
    )
    grid.cell(x: column_value, test_item(entry))
    if (column_value == 1) {
      column_value = 0
    } else if (column_value == 0) {
      column_value = 1
    }
  }
)


My intention with the if and else if syntax was to alternate between the first and second columns, cycling between 0 and 1. However, this approach didn't work, and all dictionary items ended up in the first column.
The code produced this document:-

As I'm only somewhat familiar with variable scoping, I tried using printf-style debugging to see if column_value was being updated:
#let tri(c, val) = {
  polygon.regular(
    fill: c,
    size: 5mm,
    vertices: 3,
  )
  [The value is #val]
}

#grid(
  columns: 2,
  stroke: blue,
  inset: 1mm,
  let col_val = 1,
  for i in range(4) {
    grid.cell(x: col_val, tri(green, col_val))
    if (col_val == 1) {
      col_val = 0
    } else if (col_val == 0) {
      col_val = 1
    }
  }
)


This produced

The outcome has me completely confused: the value of col_val is updated, but it doesn't affect the actual grid.cell - is this where I should start reading into state.
I suspect I might be going about this the wrong way and there is probably a more elegant and less hacky solution - if so could someone help me out?

What do you mean by "send into specific boxes"? Do you want to render it as a table or something else?

@CampbellHe Thank you for pointing out the ambiguity in language - I have updated the question. Let me know if it is still confusing.

Want to have each item in its own column, with a maximum of 2 (number of columns) elements per page? Insert colbreak(). If you want more items on a page, use table or grid instead of columns. Let us know which you want to do!

You want to render items in multiple columns and find a way to put several items in a specific column. Is this what you want?
To force a break, you can use colbreak. But I think you need to use grid to be more flexible.

Hi @Martin, I have updated the question with more details. Sorry, it took me so long to get back to the issue. Could you let me know if my question is clear.

Turns out I can just do this
#let content = yaml("information.yaml") // Load the content file

#let test_item(test_item) = [
  *#underline[#test_item.Section]* \
  #for (hit, details) in test_item.Details [
    *#hit*: #details \
  ]
  #v(-0.25em) // Add space before the next section
]

#grid(
  columns: (1fr, 1fr),
  column-gutter: 1em,
  row-gutter: 1em,
  ..content.Items.map(entry => test_item(entry))
)

The crucial part was ..{<dictionary>}.map(item => function)
Which makes

i.e. automatically distributing the items across the columns one at a time.
